# Iterating on jade-Array of objects

Tags: node.js, pug

Please help me in iterating the following array of objects. I'm able see the array of objects in console,But I could not iterate it in jade

```
[{title: "Stamp. The Hobbit", description: "Stamp. <b>The Hobbit</b>. I know 
it was on Friday …n the day when there was not a lot of creativity.", 
originalLink: null, summary: null, date: "2017-09-25T06:42:50.000Z"}
{title: "Fall/winter Tolkien/LOTR events: your &#39;go-to&#39; list", 
description: "Audiences will thrill to the music from his legend…bbit</b> 
with scores from his films: The&nbsp;...", originalLink: null, summary: 
null, date: "2017-09-25T05:26:15.000Z"},
{title: "Watch what happens when Darth Vader swaps galaxy far, far away ... 
for Middle Earth", description: "The narrative of Middle Earth: Shadow of 
War is ba…nts of <b>The Hobbit</b> and The Lord of&nbsp;...", originalLink: 
null, summary: null, date: "2017-09-25T03:56:15.000Z"}
{title: "The hobbit sword", description: "Posted by alex in kids / baby 
stuff, toys in Munster, Cork. 24 September 2017...210966215.", originalLink: 
null, summary: null, date: "2017-09-24T19:30:12.000Z"}
{title: "The hobbit as high fantasy essay", description: "Im science teacher 
is stupid hes making me write a… like r u serious. Problems of urbanization 
essay", originalLink: null, summary: null, date: "2017-09-24T19:26:02.000Z"}
{title: "Lego The Hobbit Bagend Bundle", description: "Lego <b>The 
Hobbit</b> Bagend Bundle, Used Lego &a…, Dublin, Ireland for 130.00 euros on 
Adverts.ie.", originalLink: null, summary: null, date: "2017-09-
24T10:42:38.000Z"}]
```

server code:
        res.render('index', { aaa: JSON.stringify(result) });

jade :

```
    extends layout

    block content

    script.
    console.log("hi");
    var bbb = !{aaa}
    console.log(bbb)

    each value in bbb
     p= value.title
```

Comment: It is not clear which is the real problem this question is addressing.

Comment: 1st block is the array of objects which I'm trying to iterate. 2nd block is the jade where i'm trying to iterate.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have to set value.title like this :

```
 each value in bbb
     p !{value.title}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: C:\heroku\checkRepository\views\index.jade:14 12| 13| > 14| each value in bbb 15| p !{value.title} 16| 17| Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

TypeError: C:\heroku\checkRepository\views\index.jade:14
    12|  
    13|  
  > 14|  each value in bbb
    15|   p !{value.title}
    16| 
    17| 

Cannot read property 'length' of undefined